# Jquery listener works intermittently in incognito mode chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I include jquery and use it to open all links to link.php in a new browser window:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    $('a[href*="link.php"]').attr("target", "_blank");
};
</script>
```

This works, but when I test it in incognito mode in Chrome, about 1/5 of the time, it does not work and opens in the same window. It's hard for me to debug in chrome because once it fails, I am not on my page anymore and can't inspect the js. What should my next steps be to figure out the problem?

Comment: The problem is most likely because you start with a fresh cache without anything preloaded in incognito mode. I would guess that at the time you click the page is not fully loaded. So instead of `onload`  you should try the dom ready event `$( document ).ready( function() {
    $('a[href*="link.php"]').attr("target", "_blank");
});`

Comment: This seems to work, but why does it work this way?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the comment the problem was the cache. For a new the incognito window the cache is empty, so every thing for the webpage needs loaded from the server (images, movies, scripts, ...).

The callback assigned to `window.onload`  will be executed **after all** those files a fully loaded. So as long as there is still something loading, the `target` is not set to `_blank` and as of that a click on the link will open the link in the same page.

Instead of waiting for all elements to be loaded you only need to wait until the `html` code of your page is fully loaded and the DOM becomes ready.

Do do this you need to listen to the dom ready event. In jQuery you would do that this way:

```
$( document ).ready( function() { 
   $('a[href*="link.php"]').attr("target", "_blank");
});
```

[jQuery.ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> [...]While JavaScript provides the load event for executing code when a page is rendered, this event does not get triggered until all assets such as images have been completely received. In most cases, the script can be run as soon as the DOM hierarchy has been fully constructed. The handler passed to `.ready()` is guaranteed to be executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code.[...]